# Naming an element inside javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want the select name array keys have a quotations inside. But this one doesn't generate quotations inside the brackets. How can I achieve it?

```
var id = "test";
var element = "<select name = 'unit_id["+id+"]' class = 'form-control'></select>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which is more cleaner. This does not require string concatenation and character escaping:

```js
var id = "test";
var element = `<select name = 'unit_id["${id}"]' class = 'form-control'></select>`;
console.log(element)
```

Comment: *cleaner. It's recommended to point out ES6+ incompatibilities.

Comment: @JuanElfers, I will request you update your answer mentioning such incompatibilities........and encouraging OP not to use this wonderful feature....

Comment: Mamun, I don't need to update my answer because it doesn't use template literals. It's as simple as that. We can talk about Babel if you want, but I think that is outside the scope of this topic. Have a good day.

Comment: @JuanElfers, still you can suggest the reader of your answer not use template literals...and sorry there is no `babel` tag in the question....

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```js
var id = "test";
var elemnt = "<select name=\"unit_id['" + id + "']\" class=\"form-control\"></select>";
```

Comment: This works too, but cant accept 2 answers. But thanks for time and effort

Comment: I hope your code doesn't go for a production website, because template literals have limited support amongst browsers: https://caniuse.com/#feat=template-literals